# inside naked function - how to do simple assignment

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

This is the beginning of a function that already exists and works; the commented line is my addition and its purpose is to toggle a pin.

```
inline __attribute__((naked)) 
void CScheduler::SwapToThread(void* pNew, void* pPrev)
{   
    //*(volatile DWORD*)0x400FF08C = (1 << 14);
    if (pPrev != NULL)
    {
        if (pPrev == this) // Special case to save scheduler stack on startup
        {
            asm("mov lr,%0"::"p"(&CScheduler_Run_Exit));     // load r1 with schedulers End thread
            asm("orr lr, 1");
```

When I uncomment my addition, my hard fault handler executes. I get it has something to do with this being a `naked` function but I don't understand why a simple assignment causes a problem.

Two questions:

1. Why does this line trigger the hard fault?
2. How can I perform this assignment inside this function?

Comment: I don't think your multiple `asm` should be disjoint like that.

Comment: @Eljay it's existing code and it works; I'm not concerned with style. I need to perform the assignment `*(volatile DWORD*)0x400FF08C = (1 << 14);`

Comment: Are you absolutely positively certain that your program owns address 0x400FF08C? and will tomorrow and the next day and the next? This looks pretty brittle.

Comment: @user4581301 this is a custom C++ cooperative RTOS running on ARM Cortex M4 i.e. it doesn't have virtual memory and every thread is allowed to access any memory it needs. This address is a memory-mapped IO line so no one "owns" it.

Comment: This looks very fragile... the only thing you can do reliably in a naked function is to use inline assembly, period. Even the already-existing branches aren't guaranteed to work at all. If you want to write C++ do it into a non-naked function. If you need to do that thing there, do it in assembly.

Comment: I know you don't want to hear this, but the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Function-Attributes.html) are *really* clear on this point: *While using extended asm or a mixture of basic asm and C code may appear to work, they cannot be depended upon to work reliably and are not supported.*  That said, does your RTOS support 2 threads writing to the same address at the same time?  There's no protection here to avoid it.  Can you move the memory write elsewhere and have it work?  Your OS doesn't use a protected mode, does it?  Does the scheduler disable something before calling this?

Comment: Naked functions don’t automatically include function prologues/epilogues. You have to set up the stack and the registers before and after as if you were writing pure assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was only luck that your previous version of the function happened to work without crashing.

The only thing that can safely be put inside a `naked` function is a pure Basic Asm statement.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Function-Attributes.html.  You can split it up into multiple Basic Asm statements, instead of `asm("insn \n\t"` / `"insn2 \n\t"` / `...);`, but you have to write the entire function in asm yourself.

> While using extended asm or a mixture of basic asm and C code may appear to work, they cannot be depended upon to work reliably and are not supported.

If you want to run C++ code from a naked function, you could `call` a regular function (or `bl` on ARM, `jal` on MIPS, etc.), following to the standard calling convention.

---

As for the specific reason in this case?  Maybe creating that address in a register stepped on the function args, leading to the branches going wrong?  Inspect the generated asm if you want, but it's 100% unsupported.

Or maybe it ended up using more registers, and since it's `naked` didn't properly save/restore call-preserved registers?  I haven't looked at the code-gen myself for naked functions.

Are you sure this function needs to be `naked`?  I guess that's because you manipulate `lr` to return to the new context.

If you don't want to just write more logic in asm, maybe have this function's caller do more work (and maybe pass it pointer and/or boolean args telling it more simply what it needs to do, so your inputs are already in registers, and you don't need to access globals).